# does using sort with $or prevent the use of indexes in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

it seems like using $or with a sort does a full table scan and avoids my indexes on title and keywords how can I get it to use my two indexes when using an $or query?

this query uses both the title and keywords index

```
db.tasks.find({$or: [{keywords: /^japan/}, {title:/^japan/}]})
```

this does a full table scan and uses my index total_-1

```
db.tasks.find({$or: [{keywords: /^japan/}, {title:/^japan/}]}).sort({total:-1})
```

while queries against keywords or title with a sort do use the indexes on keywords or title respectively.

```
db.tasks.find({title:/^japan/}).sort({total:-1})
db.tasks.find({keywords:/^japan/}).sort({total:-1})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting and indexes in Mongo are a complex topic. Mongo also has a special error that prevents you from doing a sort without an index if you have too many items. So it's good that you're asking about indexes, because an un-indexed sort will eventually start failing.

There is a [bug in JIRA](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1205) that seems to cover your issue, however there are some extra details to consider.

The first thing to note are your last queries:

```
db.tasks.find({title:/^japan/}).sort({total:-1})
db.tasks.find({keywords:/^japan/}).sort({total:-1})
```

These queries will fail eventually because you are only indexing on `title` not on `title/total`. Here's a script that will demonstrate the problem.

```
> db.foo.ensureIndex({title:1})
> for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++) { db.foo.insert({title: 'japan', total: i}); }
> db.foo.count()
100
> db.foo.find({title: 'japan'}).sort({total:-1}).explain()
... uses BTreeCursor title_1
> // Now try with one million items
> for(var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) { db.foo.insert({title: 'japan', total: i}); }
> db.foo.find({title: 'japan'}).sort({total:-1}).explain()
Sat Mar 31 05:57:41 uncaught exception: error: {
        "$err" : "too much data for sort() with no index.  add an index or specify a smaller limit",
        "code" : 10128
}
```

So if you plan to query & sort on `title` and `total`, then you need an index on both, in that order:

```
> db.foo.ensureIndex({title:1,total:1})
> db.foo.find({title: 'japan'}).sort({total:-1}).explain()
{
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor title_1_total_1 reverse",
...
```

The JIRA bug I listed above is for something like the following:

```
> db.foo.find({$or: [title:/^japan/, title:/^korea/]}).sort({total:-1})
```

Yours is slightly different, but it will encounter the same problem. Even if you have both indexes on `title/total` and `keyword/total` MongoDB will not be able to use indexes optimally.

Comment: if you have an index for {total:-1, title:1} and sort by {total:-1, title:1}, does it at least make the index scan more efficient?

Comment: @drogon what are you filtering by? Is there a `find()` clause in there? The JIRA bug is very specific to using `$or` clause with sorting.